# Extending a class in Java without initializing

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
public class LinkedListStructs {
    public LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();

    public LinkedListStructs(){
        ListNode h1 = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode h2 = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode h3 = new ListNode(12);
        ListNode h4 = new ListNode(9);
        ListNode h5 = new ListNode(9);
        ListNode h6 = new ListNode(4);
        l1.head = h1;
        h1.next = h2;
        h2.next = h3;
        h3.next = h4;
        h4.next = h5;
        h5.next = h6;
    }

}
```

Then I extend this in my other class:

```
public class Tester extends LinkedListStructs{

    public void removeDupsTest(){
      l1.printList();
      l1.removeDups();
      l1.printList();
      }

    }
```

I didn't initialize a new instance of `LinkedListStructs`. My question is, when I extend a class, is an instance automatically created?

I am confused because I used `LinkedList l1` in my tester class, but the object itself needs to be **initialized** with a constructor as you see with `public LinkedListStructs(){}`

So, how does it work? If I don't create an instance, initialize properties of linked list then how is it possible to use it?

Thanks

Comment: Sub-classes have access to all `public` and `protected` fields of the super-class.

Comment: When you initialized your subclass, your super class are initialized first!

Comment: You should not use an unqualified type name that matches one of the widely-used standard API types. Furthermore, if you implement a list or other container type, it would behoove you to make it generic over the type contained.

Answer (score 3):

To use your `Tester`, you have to create an instance of it. When you create it, you are calling its constructor.

Since you haven't specified a constructor, the compiler creates one for you. Your empty constructor will call the superclass constructor.

To test this, add an empty constructor to your Tester class and printLns in both the `Tester` and `LinkedListStructs` constructor. You will see the tester constructor called, which in turn will call the superclass constructor.

Note that your empty constructor must call super(), which calls the superclass constructor.

Comment: Note that the term for the constructor that the compiler provides absent a defined constructor is "default constructor". This is an important and fundamental concept for Java. Note that a programmer-provided no-argument constructor is not a default constructor, because it is defined in the class. Only when no constructor is defined in a class do you get a default constructor.

Comment: you're correct, my answer should have contained these details

Answer (score 1):

Java figures it out for you: when you extend a class that has a parameterless constructor, and do not define a constructor, your derived class automatically gets a default constructor:

> JLS section 8.8.9:
>
> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no parameters is automatically provided.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.

When you construct an instance of `Tester`, the constructor of its base class `LinkedListStructs` gets called, initializing the list `l1`.

Comment: The bit about "extend a class" actually isn't part of the rule. A default constructor is provided whenever the class doesn't provide its own, regardless. The problem with the superclass not having a parameterless constructor is not whether the subtype gets a default constructor, but whether it will work. The implicit call to `super()` will not work if the constructor thus invoked doesn't exist. This is a concern for all constructors whether explicit or default.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your doubt:

Since you have extended the LinkedListStructs and created a new class Tester (meaning of 'public class Tester extends LinkedListStructs')

All the behaviour will be available in the derived(or extended) class. This is the fundamental of Inheritance (and hence reusability). You may choose to override it as well. This is for polymorphism (you can have 'implements' to achive this).

Since, there is no explicit constructor in Tester class. The default constructor will be called, which in turn will call all its super classes constructor. [Default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) documentation can be found here.

I guess that's the direct answer to your question.

Comment: The only thing wrong with this answer is that it cites Wikipedia. At least that article in turn cites the JLS, but still, even a wrong answer above cited the correct JLS passage. A correct answer like this one certainly should.